# PHP process $_POST array

Tags: php, forms, post

Following form has repeating input fields. Each field has two hidden inputs and one text input. I want to retrieve the values of each field when posted, so that I can store in the database.

```
<form action="" method="post">

    <?php
        $arr = [30, 40, 55];        
        foreach ($arr as $code) { ?>
            <?php 
                for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++ ) { ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="field[code]" value="<?php echo $code; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="field[month]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <input type="text" name="field[amount]"><?php 
                } 
        }
    ?>

    <button name="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

I can't figure out how to run the loop to retrieve all three values of each field. I'm trying the following:

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['submit']) ){

        foreach( $_POST['field'] as $field ) { //<- problem
            $code = $field['code'];
            $month = $field['month'];
            $amount = $field['amount'];

            //insert into db
        } 

    }
?>
```

Comment: step 1) var_dump $_POST - see what's actually passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a number foreach input field.

```
<?php
       $arr = [30, 40, 55];
       foreach ($arr as $code) { ?>
           <?php
               for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++ ) { ?>
                   <input type="hidden" name="field[<?php echo $i ?>][code]" value="<?php echo $code; ?>">
                   <input type="hidden" name="field[<?php echo $i ?>][month]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                   <input type="text" name="field[<?php echo $i ?>][amount]"><?php
               }
       }

   ?>
```

On the back-end

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['submit']) ){
        foreach( $_POST['field'] as $key => $field ) { 
            $code = $field['code'];
            $month = $field['month'];
            $amount = $field['amount'];
            //insert into db
        }

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
// ...
if (isset( $_POST['submit']) && array_key_exists('field', $_POST)) {

    $code = $_POST['field']['code'];
    $month = $_POST['field']['month'];
    $amount = $_POST['field']['amount'];

    //insert into db
}
```

Or if you consider this easier to read:

```
<?php
// ...
if (isset( $_POST['submit']) && array_key_exists('field', $_POST)) {

    $field = &$_POST['field'];
    $code = $field['code'];
    $month = $field['month'];
    $amount = $field['amount'];

    //insert into db
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="" method="post">

    <?php
        $arr = [30, 40, 55];        
        foreach ($arr as $code) { ?>
            <?php 
                for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++ ) { ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="field[code][]" value="<?php echo $code; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="field[month][]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <input type="text" name="field[amount][]"><?php 
                } 
        }
    ?>

    <button name="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

then,dump($_POST);